# fixed when scrolling but stop at footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**UPDATE**
I've been testing a bit with the sticky position but it doesn't work on Safari version 11.1. Safari is the highest browser in analytics. So I guess I'm still looking for a jQuery solution. Although the answer from Michał Sadowski helped allot.

---

I'm trying to get a `fixed` element when scrolling but it needs to stop being fixed and start scrolling when it reaches the footer.

I'm using this code: [Make scrolling sidebar stop at footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651702/make-scrolling-sidebar-stop-at-footer)

My CSS, HTML are exactly the same as in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0mLzseby/1185/) fiddle right now.

But the problem is, my `fixed` element needs to have an `offset of +60` because my header (menu) is `55px` in height. I've got the offset to work sort off. 
Right now, I use the following code.

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop()+60;
    var footer_top = $("#footer").offset().top;
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    var div_height = $("#sticky").height();

    var padding = 20;  // tweak here or get from margins etc

    if (window_top + div_height > footer_top - padding)
        $('#sticky').css({top: (window_top + div_height - footer_top + padding) * -1})
    else if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky').css({top: 60})
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

This kind of works. But when I reach the `#footer` the `top` jumps from `60px` to `-1.8414`. So the transition isn't seamless. It "jumps" when I reach the footer.

I've tried a whole bunch of things.

- Like adding `60px` to the `#sticky` div.
- When It removes the class `stick` I followed that up with `$('#sticky').css({top: 60})`

But nothing takes away the "jump" is there anyone who could help me to get this to work or has a similar code snippet?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? Because if you can make do with just modern ones, you can just add in css: `position: sticky; top: 60px;`

Comment: Just the modern once. No need for the old once... The problem is it needs to stop being fixed when it reaches the footer. The footer is really long (don't ask) so the element should scroll upwards when it hits the footer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it depends a lot on your html structure. But let's say you have it like that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sticky">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, in css:

```
.content{
  position: relative
}
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
}
```

It should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Wow, is that position sticky, new or have I been living under a rock? This looks like its working.

Looking at: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky it looks like it would support most of the browers visiting the site... Is there a jquery solution as well because in edge it kind of "flickers"?

Comment: It's a native solution, so you can polyfill it for browsers that don't support it well yet - but overall, yes, it's a pretty new spec.

Comment: I've been testing a bit with the `sticky` position but it doesn't work on Safari version 11.1. Safari is the highest browser in analytics. So I guess I'm still looking for a jQuery solution.