# fixed header and fixed sidenav with static footer, side nav is collapsing with footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Position of header is fixed, and side nav should move up and down with scroll so I applied position fixed for side nav, the issue I am facing now is its collapsing with footer.

```
<div class="header" style="background: #555;color: #f1f1f1;position:fixed;" id="myHeader">
    <h2>I am header you can change my coding but my position should be fixed</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div style="height:1400px"></div>
    <div style="width: 200px; background-color: #999; position: fixed; right: 20px; top: 200px; height: 383px;">
        <h3>I should move with scroll but should not collapse with footer</h3>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 1800px; background-color: #996; right: 20px; top: 300px; height: 383px;">
        <h2>I am footer</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: side nav should be fixed or should it move with scroll ? what i got from your question is you want it to scroll and stop at footer, is this the required functionality ?

Comment: To move the side nav with scroll, I set position:fixed, and later I want to stop at footer. My project is angular, got something in jquery and trying to implement but its  a long way

Comment: is jQuery an option then try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651702/make-scrolling-sidebar-stop-at-footer  if not sorry don't know angular but quick google search found this you can try this and use it https://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/angularjs/angular-directive-check-scroll-position-element-example-and-demo.

Comment: mmm.. I am working on Angular2, and because of it offsetheight of footer is zero because its different component